# How to specify that a value is LESS THAN in a parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that returns various products with the margin we make on each one. I have set up a parameter in the query `@Margin`. I have set the Parameter data type to integer, but I want the parameter to return all products with a margin of less than 15%.

[image]

If I enter the value as <15 then this is not an integer

**How do I set the parameter value to <15 (less than 15%)?**

***EDIT***

My mistake was setting up the parameter in the query incorrectly. I had used `= @Margin` when I should have been using `< @Margin`. This allowed me to simply change the value from `<15` to `15`. This gave me my desired result.

Comment: Use cast or convert operator concatenating with `>` operator.

Comment: That dialog box is about *parameter values*, not criteria. What does your *query* look like?

Comment: You can, but should **not** add filters to the query as they are applied *after* the query results return. The query itself should filter the data, eg `Where MyTable.MyField < @Margin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the parameter Margin as integer and provide the value. Then in the data set part you can write the query to filter it less than @Margin value.

Check the image below.

[image: Use parameter value to filter results]

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression as query. Found here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0abbeb09-879c-404d-9286-0d1b72b49870/how-to-add-a-report-parameter-to-let-user-choose-less-than-greater-than-or-all-records?forum=sqlreportingservices

A TSQL sample would be:

```
 ="SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE COLUMN" & Parameters!Operator.Value & Parameters!Hour.Value
```